# Is it realistic widget on Angular which will work on all platforms?

Tags: angular, widget

Is it realistic to create a widget on Angular (not an iframe) so that in the future it can be installed on other frameworks React, Vue (by node_modules), WordPress plugins and others?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) which offer a native-JS, limited version of what you appear to be asking about.

Comment: Thanks, this is a little different, but very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing and studying third-party sites, I decided to use iframe. They are used to build bank widgets for payment, buying tickets, and so on.

If you need to organize the communication of our  widget with the application inside an iframe, for example, we want to stretch the frame size to fit the content when opening the widget. To do this, we need to tell the size of the content from the iframe to the parent window. This can be easily done via [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).